# Apparent paradox with power series convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm having problem figuring out how these three facts are mutually consistent:

1. Call a set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ to be *concirclic* if for some real number $R$, if you let  $A$ be the (open) ball **centered at zero** with radios $R$ and $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$ then $A \subset S \subset \overline{A}$.  For any power series $f(z) = \sum a_i z^i$, let $S_f := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | f(z) \text{ is finite } \}$. Then $S$ is *concirclic*
2. If you let $f(z) = \sum (z-.5)^i$ then $S_f = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}, |z - .5| < 1 \}$. In particular, $S_f$ is **not** *concirclic*.
3. If you define $b_i$ as the sum of coefficients of $z^i$ in $\sum_{k \geq 0} (z-.5)^k$, then $b_i$ is well defined (i.e is not divergent). Then $f(z) = \sum b_i z^i$, and hence $S_f$ is *concirclic*.

I'm making some very stupid mistake but can't figure it lol

Comment: Number $2$ requires $\left|z-\frac12\right|<1$ to converge (otherwise the test for divergence applies). So it appears to me that it *is* concirclic. Note that even if some of the boundary was included, it would still be concirclic.

Comment: @Clayton Sorry I don't get your comment - from where is divergence test coming ?

Comment: How did you get $S_f$ in 2? The series diverges in, for example, $-\frac{1}{2}$, as common term is $(-1)^k$ and it doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: You said $z\neq1.5$ and $|z-.5|\leq1$, but you need $\left|z-\frac12\right|<1$.

Comment: Sorry it was a minor typo, I have changed $\leq$ to $<$. Now I hope what I intend to say is clear ?

Comment: Ok, now (with changing equality to strict) it's correct (though you don't need to add $z \neq 1.5$ anymore)

Comment: You haven't described why $S_f$ is not concirclic. Your description seems that it **is** concirclic (it's just an open disk).

Comment: @Clayton Isn't it obvious ? What's the $R$ if $S_f$ is concirclic ? Note that $A$ is **centered at $0$** and $A \subset S_f \subset \overline{A}$

Comment: Ah, I missed that; I think it should be the center of the power series.

Comment: @Clayton So where I'm making the thinking error (in the original questoin) ?

Comment: I think your definition of concirclic is not general enough. It specifies that definition for a Maclaurin series; a general Taylor series is centered at a nonzero point, and the center of the disk is shifted accordingly.

Comment: Can you give a source for the definition?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot arbitrarily rearrange/regroup a series and always expect it to stay convergent/divergent. For example, $0+0+0+\dots$ converges, but $(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots=1-1+1-1+\dots$ diverges. You start with $\sum_{k\ge 0}(z-1/2)^k$, which is absolutely convergent on an open circle of radius $1$ centered at $1/2$. After some rearrangements, you end at $\sum_i b_i z^i$. This is still convergent on the original set, and equal to the original series there, but is also convergent on the larger circle which is centered at the origin with radius $3/2$.

In detail, you have
$$
\sum_{k\ge 0}(z-1/2)^k=\frac1{1-(z-\frac12)}=\frac23\cdot \frac1{1-\frac23z}=\sum_{i\ge 0}\underbrace{(2/3)^{i+1}}_{b_i}z^i
$$

The fact that your rearrangements lead to a correct answer in the original region of convergence (the circle of radius $1$ centered at $1/2$) suggests that they can be justified in this region, but for now I cannot see how.

Comment: The original series converged uniformly at neighborhood of $0$, so we can reorder terms there.

Answer (score -1):

You defined $S_f$ as the domain of convergence of Taylor's series centered at $0$, and such domain is indeed concirclic (upd: if radius of convergence is finite). But in 2 you take Taylor series centered at $\frac{1}{2}$ - and it's domain of convergence in general differs from domain of convergence of series centered at $0$. So $S_f \neq \{z: |z - 0.5| < 1\}$

If you calculate $b_i$ you will note that $b_i = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{2z}{3}\right)^i$, and $\sum b_i z_i$ converges at, say $z = -1$, while original series diverges there.